Does the fourier transform of the product of test function and bounded function belong to $L^p$?
Let $\mathcal D(\mathbb R^n)$ be the set of test functions, i.e., functions in $C^\infty(\mathbb R^n)$ with compact support. Let $f\in \mathcal D(\mathbb R^n)$, and $m:\mathbb R^n\to \mathbb C$ be a bounded function. Put $(mf)(x):=m(x)f(x)$.
Then, for all $p\in(1,\infty)$, does $\mathcal F[mf]$, the fourier transform of $mf$, belong to $L^p(\mathbb R^n)$ ?
Simple estimate $\int|\mathcal F[mf](\xi)|^pd\xi\leqq (\sup_x |m(x)|)^p\int\left(\int_{supp f}|f(x)|dx\right)^pd\xi$ doesn't work.
Does anyone have any idea or counter example ?

First, your function $mf\in L^1\cap L^2$, so its Fourier transform $\mathcal{F}(mf)$ is in $C^0_0\cap L^2$, and so in any $L^p$ with $p\in [2,\infty]$.
But $\mathcal{F}(mf)$ is in general not in $L^1$, since for instance if $m(x)=\mathbf{1}_{[-1,1]}(x)$ and $f$ is any function of $C^\infty_c$ with $f=1$ on $[-1,1]$, then $mf = m = \mathbf{1}_{[-1,1]}$ whose Fourier transform is of the form $C\,\frac{\sin(ax)}{x}$ which is not integrable.
Not sure about $L^p$ with $p\in(1,2)$.

Thanks for your answer. This seems difficult for $1<p<2.$
